# Syntax error while executing mocha test runner

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have written a small Node.js app containing the following code and it's corresponding API test.
    However when I invoke the test, the following error is displayed about mocha:

```
C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha:13
const {deprecate} = require('../lib/utils');
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:933:3
```

C:\Users\HP\Downloads\NodeJSPortable\Data>

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea what could be the fix?

Comment: Please show the test code. Also check the code before this line...there might be an unclosed bracket or something similar, so the new line comes out as "unexpected token"...

Comment: In-line the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You're just using an old version of javascript. Upgrade to a newer version of nodejs, or change it to something backward-compatible. `const deprecate = require('../lib/utils').deprecate;` should do it.